# Input file multiple : show all the file names at the same time using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to take the picture and name but it does not work.

```js
<script>

var imagesPreview = function(input, append) {
        if(input.files) {
          for(i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
            var filename = input.files.item(i).name;
            
            var reader = new FileReader();
            $(reader).load(function(e){
              $(append).append(
                '<div class="frame col-md-3" align="center">'+
                '<img src="'+e.target.result+'" class="img">'+
                '<div style="word-wrap:break-word; margin-top:5px">'+filename+'</div>'+
                '</div>'
              );
            })
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
          }
        }
      };

      $('#images').on('change', function(e) {
        imagesPreview(this, '.data-image');
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Describe more what you want to achieve please, where you want to display those names ? do you want to select multiple pictures at the same time ?

Comment: error while running code

Comment: _error while running code_ ? the code work just fine..

Comment: I want to display multiple picture and name at the same time. Display multiple picture is work, but display name it does not work. Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the file name to the load function as a data parameter like :

```
$(reader).load({
     fname: input.files.item(i).name
  }, function(e) {
    var filename = e.data.fname;

    $(append).append(
      '<div class="frame col-md-3" align="center">' +
      '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" class="img">' +
      '<div style="word-wrap:break-word; margin-top:5px">' + filename + '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
})
```

```js
var imagesPreview = function(input, append) {
  if (input.files) {
    for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {

      var reader = new FileReader();
      $(reader).load({
        fname: input.files.item(i).name
      }, function(e) {
        var filename = e.data.fname;

        $(append).append(
          '<div class="frame col-md-3" align="center">' +
          '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" class="img">' +
          '<div style="word-wrap:break-word; margin-top:5px">' + filename + '</div>' +
          '</div>'
        );
      })
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    }
  }
};

$('#images').on('change', function(e) {
  imagesPreview(this, '.data-image');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="images" multiple="multiple" />
<div class="data-image"></div>
```

Comment: I've put it, here I just show the javascript code. The problem is, when I select multiple files, the filename appears only one name

Comment: Check my update passing the file name as parameter to the load function...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var imagesPreview = function(input, element) {
  if (input.files) {
    for (const file of input.files) {
      var filename = file.name;
      append(file, filename, element);
    }
  }
};

const append = function(file, filename, element) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  $(reader).load(function(e) {
    $(element).append(
      '<div class="frame col-md-3" align="center">' +
      '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" class="img">' +
      '<div style="word-wrap:break-word; margin-top:5px">' + filename + '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
  })
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

$('#images').on('change', function(e) {
  imagesPreview(this, '.data-image');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="images" multiple />
<div class="data-image"></div>
```

You needed to add `multiple` to the html input element like so:
`<input type="file" id="images" multiple />`

Comment: I've put it, still can't display many pictures and image names

Comment: I the code I provided, when you run you should see filenames and images.

Comment: the image name is still the same when selecting many files, it should show the name of each selected image

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the filereader, use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) and make it a litle easier for you since it then will become syncron

```
function imagesPreview(input, append) {
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var $elm = $(append);

  if (input.files) {
    for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      var file = input.files[i];
      var src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

      $elm.append(
        '<div class="frame col-md-3" align="center">' +
          '<img src="' + src + '" class="img">' +
          '<div style="word-wrap:break-word; margin-top:5px">' + file.name + '</div>' +
        '</div>'
      );
    }
  }
};

$('#images').on('change', function(e) {
  imagesPreview(this, '.data-image');
});
```